# Not getting desired output while Locating Descendent Elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am not getting the colored output by the given code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("p").find("span").addClass("selected");
   });

   </script>
   <style>
      .selected { color:red; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

   <p>This is 1st paragraph and <span>THIS IS RED</span></p>
   <p>This is 2nd paragraph and <span>THIS IS ALSO RED</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything that I am missing? Thanks,

Comment: This works here: http://jsfiddle.net/DFYc4/    using lastest jquery

Comment: No I thought so too, but he used jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: @koopajah  Ya i see it too late

Comment: it works fine !!, which browser do u use ?

Comment: I am using w3schools try it editor, and also I have checked it in IE9.

Comment: I just tested locally with this version of jquery and IE9 and it works fine

Comment: do you get the jquery loaded? in w3schools try it editor

Comment: I have changes jquery src to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js", now the code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:  **http://jsfiddle.net/gaHhv/1/**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

although `you should use latest jquery`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting anything in a console log? The code is fine see it working here, ensure your Jquery src is correct

```
$("p").find("span").addClass("selected");​
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YjCWw/)

Comment: No I thought so too, but he used jQuery 1.3.2